# Why was Gemini and now Claude (the chatbots) unavailiable in Canada?

Tags: canada, artificial-intelligence

When Google released it's Gemini chatbot last year, it was unavailiable in Canada. I thought this was an odd case, but now there's a new chatbot called Claude and it's also unavailiable in Canada. Both are availiable in pretty much the entire world minus a handful of countries (mostly obvious things like North Korea). Why are companies being so cautious of Canada when releasing AI? Does it have something to do with bill C-18?

Comment: "(mostly obvious things like North Korea)"... and the European Union. Btw Gemini is now available in Canada.

Comment: How is the business decision of Google a question about the law?

Comment: @Trish because another company took the same decision and why would it be anything but a legal one.

Comment: That's like saying Ford decided to make cars. So did Daimler.